# Mismatched range sizes in FILTER()

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a pivot table of info, with totals (the totals columns contain the word "Total"), that I would like to process further. I created a new sheet and use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA('Pivot Table mins'!A:B)
```

to grab the first two columns.

But then I want to "import" over JUST the columns that have the word "Total" in them, so I created:

```
=FILTER('Sheet'!A:X,MMULT(REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!A:X,"Total"),ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&COLUMNS('Sheet'!A:X)))^0))
```

e.g. if the Pivot Table data spans columns A to Z, but only columns D & F have the keyword "Total", I only want to "import" those columns.

However I am getting an error message:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1250. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

I've read that it could be that the ranges do not match, however I have all ranges matching.

Side note: There are 1242 rows in both sheets.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Copy Data', [ 
      { name: 'Copy', functionName: 'copyTotalColumns' },
      ]);  
}

function copyTotalColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet")
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var lastColumn = s.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow= s.getLastRow()
  var startCol=3 //column to start total rows
  var data = s.getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();//get headers
  for(var i=0;i<data[0].length;i++){
    if( data[0][i]=="Total"){
      var copyFrom=s.getRange(2, i+1, lastRow,1).getValues()//get total column
      var copyTo=s1.getRange(2, startCol,       
lastRow,1).setValues(copyFrom)//set total column on new sheet
      startCol=startCol+1 //index column
 }
  }}
```

Comment: The columns that have the word "Total" in them constantly change, so it isn't possible to specify certain columns.

Comment: @Brittany Greve See revised answer.

Comment: Where in Google Sheets would I implement this? I'm looking for the most efficient way to do so since this sheet will be used with multiple users. Thanks.

Comment: I added a create menu to the code to create a custom menu to run this from. From the main menu, go to Tools - Script Editor. Delete what is there and copy the above code. Save it and run it. Answer the prompts. Make sire you have a Sheet2 to accept the new data. Run the script from the menu. To share with others, they will need edit permission. Google it. If you want to share your spreadsheet, I could help more.